# php session array for shopping cart is not updating

Tags: php, arrays, session-variables, shopping-cart

Currently I m making a shopping cart using php session array. I m a pure noob. The problem I m facing is the session variable is not updating accordingly. when the same product is given it is supposed to increase the quantity. But it is not doing that:

```
<?php
session_start();
// get the product id
//$id = isset($_GET['productID']) ;
$pid = $_GET['productID'] ;

/* 
 * check if the 'cart' session array was created
 * if it is NOT, create the 'cart' session array
 */
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cart']=array("id","qty");
}

// check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if (in_array($pid, $_SESSION['cart'])){
    $cart[$pid]++;
    echo "yes";
    include "../includes/dbconn.php";
    $result=mysql_query("select product_name from mast_product where id=$pid");
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $sizes=sizeof($cart);
    print_r($cart);
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Success','pname' => $row[0],'total'=> '3'));
}

// else, add the item to the array
else{
    $cart[$pid]=1;
    echo "No";
   include "../includes/dbconn.php";
    $result=mysql_query("select product_name from mast_product where id=$pid");
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $sizes=sizeof($cart);
    print_r($cart);
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Success','pname' => $row[0],'total'=>$cart[$pid]));
}

 ?>
```

output for print_r($cart) is: NoArray ( [28] => 1 ) {"msg":"Success","pname":"HTC One","total":1}

everytime same output.

Comment: I would STRONGLY suggest moving to an object-oriented programming methodology here.  That being said, I don't see where `$cart` is even being set initially. I also don't understand what this does -  `$_SESSION['cart'] = array("id","qty");` Why have id and qty entries here, and why as two values in the array (as it seems you are trying to use product id's for key and quantity for value)?

Comment: Yes I wanted to do that. But I had no clear concept about key and value in php array.

Comment: can you please tell what will be solution ???

Answer (score 0):

You are storing `array("id","qty")` in the `$_SESSION['cart']` variable every time a new session is created.

But in the following code `if(in_array($pid, $_SESSION['cart'])) {...}` you are checking if `$pid` is in the `$_SESSION` array which cannot be true as you have stored `array("id","qty")` when the session was made. So every time its going to your else block and the same output is being generated as there is no db update query.

You need to store the `$pid` in the $_SESSION array not `array("id","qty")`

Code:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $pid;
}
```

Also you need to initialize the $cart variable at the beginning.

The following if check should be like

```
if ($pid == $_SESSION['cart']) {...} or if (in_array($pid, $_SESSION)){...}
```

not

```
if (in_array($pid, $_SESSION['cart'])){...}
```

as in_array() needs the second param to be an array when here its a number.

Comment: I have just modified this like the following:

    if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cart'] = $pid;
}


// check if the item is in the array, if it is, do not add
if (in_array($pid, $_SESSION['cart'])){
    $cart[$pid]++;...
...........

still the same output...

Comment: Have you defined the $cart variable anywhere? How is it initialized? for the $cart[$pid]++; to work it must have some value first.

Comment: also in_array($pid, $_SESSION['cart']) is always false as in_array needs the second param to be an array whereas here its an number because $_SESSION['cart'] gives $pid which is a number. Change the if check to if($pid == $_SESSION['cart']). see the edited answer.